# How to draw noncontinuous lines with one vertex array

Tags: objective-c, ios, graphics, opengl-es

I want to draw using gldrawarray in opengl es with a vertex array of 33 numbers, which is 11 points in 3D. And I also want to add the points into the vertex array by 33*n, so I need to draw many same shapes using each 11 points in the vertex array which contains more than 11 points. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`first` and `count` parameters](http://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glDrawArrays.xml) to issue multiple draw calls, one per object:

```
int verticesPerObject = 11;
for(int i = 0; i < totalVerticesInArray; i += verticesPerObject)
{
    glDrawArrays(GL_LINE_LOOP, i, verticesPerObject);
}
```